# Using $compile to compile a piece of HTML in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, compilation, angular-directive

In my controller,

I have a piece of code that outputs a string `self.selectedProduct` using `template string` expression..

This works as expected.

```
var productName = `
   <div class='vertical-spacer'>|</div><div> ${self.selectedProduct}</div>`;
```

But when I want to add a directive that code breaks

```
        var template = angular.element("<my-dropdown domainobject="domainobject"></my-dropdown>");
        var linkFn = $compile(template)($scope);
        productName = $(`
                                <div class='domain-wks-vertical-spacer'>|</div><div>`);
        productName.append(linkFn);
```

So instead of the `${self.selectedProduct}` I want to show the directive.

But I am not able to.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the string using double quotes (") inside another double quote.

Try this:

```
var template = angular.element('<my-dropdown domainobject="domainobject"></my-dropdown>');
```